# Scrape Realtime data using VBA

Tags: javascript, html, json, vba, web-scraping

I want to scrape realtime data from https://iboard.ssi.com.vn/bang-gia/hose using VBA.

My code is as follows; but it does not return the html file with data contained inside. I looked for but could not find the link to JSON data either.

```
Sub Get_ssi_data()
       
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    xmlhttp.Open "GET", "https://iboard.ssi.com.vn/bang-gia/hose"
    xmlhttp.send
    
    Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText
      
End Sub
```

Could you please suggest what to do to be able to get  the real time data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is unclear which part of the data are you looking for but I assume that you want the main table.

Multiple APIs are called to the endpoint `https://gateway-iboard.ssi.com.vn/graphql` , with different request body to get the specific information.

From the DevTools, the request body for the main table is as below:

```
{"operationName":"stockRealtimes","variables":{"exchange":"hose"},"query":"query stockRealtimes($exchange: String) {\n  stockRealtimes(exchange: $exchange) {\n    stockNo\n    ceiling\n    floor\n    refPrice\n    stockSymbol\n    stockType\n    exchange\n    matchedPrice\n    matchedVolume\n    priceChange\n    priceChangePercent\n    highest\n    avgPrice\n    lowest\n    nmTotalTradedQty\n    best1Bid\n    best1BidVol\n    best2Bid\n    best2BidVol\n    best3Bid\n    best3BidVol\n    best4Bid\n    best4BidVol\n    best5Bid\n    best5BidVol\n    best6Bid\n    best6BidVol\n    best7Bid\n    best7BidVol\n    best8Bid\n    best8BidVol\n    best9Bid\n    best9BidVol\n    best10Bid\n    best10BidVol\n    best1Offer\n    best1OfferVol\n    best2Offer\n    best2OfferVol\n    best3Offer\n    best3OfferVol\n    best4Offer\n    best4OfferVol\n    best5Offer\n    best5OfferVol\n    best6Offer\n    best6OfferVol\n    best7Offer\n    best7OfferVol\n    best8Offer\n    best8OfferVol\n    best9Offer\n    best9OfferVol\n    best10Offer\n    best10OfferVol\n    buyForeignQtty\n    buyForeignValue\n    sellForeignQtty\n    sellForeignValue\n    caStatus\n    tradingStatus\n    currentBidQty\n    currentOfferQty\n    remainForeignQtty\n    session\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n"}
```

So you need to send the above request body to the endpoint which will gives you a JSON response containing the raw data of the main table which you will then need to process them on your own to get what you want.

```
Private Sub Get_ssi_data()
           
    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP")
    
    Dim reqBody As String
    reqBody = "{""operationName"":""stockRealtimes"",""variables"":{""exchange"":""hose""},""query"":""query stockRealtimes($exchange: String) {\n  stockRealtimes(exchange: $exchange) {\n    stockNo\n    ceiling\n    floor\n    refPrice\n    stockSymbol\n    stockType\n    exchange\n    matchedPrice\n    matchedVolume\n    priceChange\n    priceChangePercent\n    highest\n    avgPrice\n    lowest\n    nmTotalTradedQty\n    best1Bid\n    best1BidVol\n    best2Bid\n    best2BidVol\n    best3Bid\n    " & _
                "best3BidVol\n    best4Bid\n    best4BidVol\n    best5Bid\n    best5BidVol\n    best6Bid\n    best6BidVol\n    best7Bid\n    best7BidVol\n    best8Bid\n    best8BidVol\n    best9Bid\n    best9BidVol\n    best10Bid\n    best10BidVol\n    best1Offer\n    best1OfferVol\n    best2Offer\n    best2OfferVol\n    best3Offer\n    best3OfferVol\n    best4Offer\n    best4OfferVol\n    best5Offer\n    best5OfferVol\n    best6Offer\n    best6OfferVol\n    best7Offer\n    best7OfferVol\n    best8Offer\n    best8OfferVol\n    best9Offer\n    best9OfferVol\n   best10Offer\n    best10OfferVol\n    buyForeignQtty\n    buyForeignValue\n    sellForeignQtty\n    sellForeignValue\n    caStatus\n    tradingStatus\n    currentBidQty\n    currentOfferQty\n    remainForeignQtty\n    session\n    __typename\n  }\n}\n""}"
    
    xmlhttp.Open "POST", "https://gateway-iboard.ssi.com.vn/graphql", False
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
    xmlhttp.send reqBody
    'xmlhttp.send (reqBody) 'For Excel 2013 (Credit to SIM in comment)

    Debug.Print xmlhttp.responseText

End Sub
```

## EDIT - On finding the request body

Under Network tab in Chrome Devtools, you will see that the website made several requests to `graphql` (Filter by Fetch/XHR to get a smaller result in the list)

[image]

Because they all call to the same endpoint which makes it difficult to identify the correct table, I click onto each request and look at its Response tab (that is the JSON string).

Below you can see that I found the request that returns the main table's data (the JSON string is usually in 1 long line, you can click Pretty Print (circled in red) to make it easier to read)

[image]

Once you found the request that you want, go back to **Headers** tab and look at the end of the tab, you will find **Request Payload** section which is the request body. You can click `view source` to get a plain text version which you use to copy-paste.

[image]

Comment: Some version of excel might complain if you use `xmlhttp.send reqBody` instead of `xmlhttp.send (reqBody)`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, I'm not aware of this potential issue. Do you know the specific Excel version that requires `(reqBody)`? @SIM

Comment: Yeah, excel 2013 , for instance.

Comment: @SIM Cool, I have edited my answer and included it just in case!

Comment: Oh, that 's great @Raymond Wu and Sim, so quick and so efficient. It may take me some time to fully understand  the codes that you share, but with these coding lines, I  have now overcome the feeling of being stuck, and I can move on to process the JSON data by myself . Thank you both very much for your help.

Comment: @Cao feel free to ask if you need help explaining certain lines

Comment: If you need help processing JSON data, look into JSONConverter on github (just google "JSONConverter vba")

Comment: @Raymond Wu, Can you tell me how to find  the request body for the main table that you mentioned: {"operationName":"stockRealtimes","variables":{"exchange":"hose"},"query":"query ......  I tried with Chrome Devtools but could not find it.

Comment: @CaoDoremi As requested, I have edited my answer to add on a section on how to find the request body. I hope it's clear enough!

Comment: Thanks for your detailed instructions, @Raymond Wu. So far I know how to find the request body.; but another problem arises when I process JSON data. I have imported JsonConverter.bas from github as instructed; but when I add these lines into your sub: Dim JSON As Object: Set JSON = jsonConverter.ParseJson(xmlhttp.ResponseText) : n = JSON.Count: MsgBox n  ;  I get n=1. It seems to me that JSON is not properly parsed.

Comment: @CaoDoremi That might be correct, try `Debug.Print JSON("data")("stockRealtimes").Count` and see the number in Immediate window (this is a better way to debug than using `Msgbox`). You just need to learn how to access the collection of dictionaries that is created by `ParseJson`.

Comment: If the number in immediate window is few hundreds then you should get "AAA" or some stock symbol by doing `Debug.Print JSON("data")("stockRealtimes")(1)("stockSymbol")`. Modify it to get the other data (you can do a loop like `For i = 1 to JSON("data")("stockRealtimes").Count` then `Debug.Print JSON("data")("stockRealtimes")(i)("stockSymbol")` to print out all stock symbols)

Comment: Perfect, @Raymond Wu, you must have been a teacher with pedagogical skills and enthusiasm, it is easy to understand following your step by step guide. I will give it a try applying these techniques to scrape data from another website.  Big Thanks!